# Changing data in multiple documents using Dialogbox in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, dialog

Im creating agent to change specific fields in multiple documents(selected in view) using dialogbox.
This is my code so far :

```
Sub Initialize
Dim s As New NotesSession 
Dim db As NotesDatabase 
Dim g_doc As NotesDocument
Dim g_col As NotesDocumentCollection    
Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace  
Set db = s.CurrentDatabase  
Set g_col = db.Unprocesseddocuments
Set g_doc = g_col.Getfirstdocument


Call ws.Dialogbox("(book_data_agent)", True, True, False, True, False, False, "Change data")


 Its easy to change fields for one document, but now im stuck when I try to change values in all selected documents.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the "StampAll"- Method of NotesDocumentCollection.

```vb
Call g_col.StampAll( "ItemName", "NewValue" )
```